# Do GCP MIGs have a constraint that all their VMs must use the same CPU platform?

Tags: google-compute-engine

We have very long lived MIGs and I am seeing that all their VMs are on "Intel Cascade Lake" even though "Intel Ice Lake" is available in the the datacenter. The documentation mentions that the VMs in a MIG are "identical" and I was wondering whether this includes the underlying CPU platform even though, for example N2, supports multiple.